# What is the standard way to implement an API sandbox?

Tags: rest, language-agnostic, sandbox

so it occurred to me that it would be helpful in the development of my backend to have a managed sandbox, like a development environment without having to set up a separate database. To be more specific I'm using Postgresql and Node.js, but I doubt that makes a difference.

So my question is, how do services such as PayPal commonly implement a "sandbox" for developers who use their API to play with that is separate from their real data? In my case all that I want is a database sandbox that operates separately from the main database for the backend developers. My first idea on this is to tag every row with their specific sandbox or production id, but that seems inefficient. Is there another way to implement this idea?

Comment: why is setting up a separate DB not an option for you?

Comment: That's kinda what I wanna stream line by making a sandbox. I want a sandbox to be able to be created programmatically and have every user of the API have one

Comment: @AlexandruMarculescu

Comment: you usually just restore the Production DB on a different server, that's hit through an application that's also deployed on a different server (than Production) - this way you get a sandbox/preproduction environment that's as close as possible to the production one, and thus be ideal for testing

Comment: @Duxducis would you like to share how you eventually go about solving this?